# Combinations question related to cards game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In how many ways can a player get 4-4-3-2 (4 cards from 1 suite, 4 cards from one suite, 3 cards from one suite and 2 cards from the last suite)?

I calculated this way, but my answer is supposed to be divided by 2, to arrive at the correct answer. But I am not able to understand why we need to divide by 2. My approach is given below:

Choose one of the 4 suites and then choose 4 cards from that suite. Choose another suite from the remaining 3 suites and then choose 4 cards from that suite. Choose one suite from the remaining 2 suites and choose 3 cards from that suite. Finally choose 2 cards from the remaining suite. Following this logic, we get

$$
{4 \choose 1} {13 \choose 4} {3 \choose 1} {13 \choose 4} {2 \choose 1} {13 \choose 3} {1 \choose 1} {13 \choose 2} = 273705800000
$$

But the answer is supposed to be 136852900000

Comment: The result of the product you wrote is $273705775200$.

Comment: You could first choose four $\heartsuit$ then four $\diamondsuit$.  Or you could choose four $\diamondsuit$ then four $\heartsuit$.  What's the difference?

Comment: Those $2$ suites from which you have to choose $4$ cards each is where the problem is. You calculation method yields duplicate count. You need to divide the result by $2!$ (if you had $3$ such suites, then you'd have to divide it by $3!$).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answering my question

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the first of your two suits are spades and hearts, then by ${4\choose 1}{3\choose1}$ you are specifying their *order*, viz spades-hearts and hearts-spades,which is not needed.  The correct formulation is thus

$${4 \choose 2} {13 \choose 4}^2 {2 \choose 1} {13 \choose 3} {1 \choose 1} {13 \choose 2}$$

Similarly, for a suit distribution of 3-3-3-4, the correct formula would be

$${4\choose 3}{13\choose 3}^3{1\choose1}{13\choose 4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have over counted ways to choose four cards from each of two suits, since the order you choose the suits does not matter.

You could first choose four $\heartsuit$ then four $\diamondsuit$.   Or you could choose four $\diamondsuit$ then four $\heartsuit$.   But what's the difference?

You must count ways to choose:

- Two of the four suits.
- Four of thirteen cards from each of these.
- One of the two remaining suits.
- Three of thirteen cards from this.
- Two of thirteen cards from the one remaining suit.